# How to hide a Model3D

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

How can I "hide" a Model3D in WPF? I tried setting

```
((GeometryModel3D)book).Material = new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.Transparent);
((GeometryModel3D)book).BackMaterial = new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.Transparent);
```

and it works but some elements behind it become invisible too and only those parts covered by the invisible element.

Is there another way to do so? Except placing the element outside the view?

Thank you.

Comment: Opacity, Visibility, there's options. Hard to visualize your issue though, a quick image of what you have and what you want might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: I had that strange effect because I was using a "DiffuseMaterial", the same code with an "EmissiveMaterial" works perfectly.

P.S. Model3D does not have Opacity/ Visibility properties.

Thank you anyway.